# I'm trying to make a dropdown list alphabetical order using aspx. Where can I add that in the following code below?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code here creates a dropdown menu of abbreviations for different location. What I'm trying to do is to get all the abbreviation in alphabetical order. How do I go about doing that?

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_loc" runat="server" DataSourceID="CriticalLog" 
        DataTextField="abbrev" DataValueField="recordKey" Height="16px" 
        style="margin-bottom: 8px" 
        ToolTip="Select your Location for updating." AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddl_loc_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" CssClass="auto-style9" Width="184px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">&quot;--  Choose a Location  --&quot;
        </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CriticalLog" runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CriticalLogConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [name], [recordKey],[abbrev], [phone2], [phone1] , [type] FROM [location] where [name] NOT LIKE '(%' ORDER BY [type],[abbrev]">

                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <div class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Loc" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large"
                            Font-Underline="True" ToolTip="Location"></asp:Label>

                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    </div>
```

Comment: add the code of your Datasource `CriticalLog` - imo you should sort the result there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your SelectCommand's `order by`:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [name], [recordKey],[abbrev], [phone2], [phone1] , [type] FROM [location] where [name] NOT LIKE '(%' ORDER BY [abbrev]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you useally need (have) some data source for the drop down.

So, say this drop down:

```
        <h3>Select Hotel</h3>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel2" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            Width="288px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Now, to fill above, we go:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCombo2();
    }

    void LoadCombo2()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable rst = MyRst(strSQL);
        cboHotel2.DataSource = rst;
        cboHotel2.DataBind();
        cboHotel2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
    }
```

And now we see this:

[image]

So, really, the "common" way to approach this problem, is we order/sort and setup the data BEFORE we sent it to the drop down list.

And I did use that helper routine MyRst, since that just saves a lot of re-typing of code. that helper routine (I usually put in a global set of routines - used it for years). Is this:

```
    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So, be it some list, some table, or whatever data you have to drive the combo box? Sort the data before you SEND the data to the drop down.

Lists, even tables (default view) all have the ability to sort - even if the original  source data was not sorted.

Comment: OP already has a Datasource `DataSourceID="CriticalLog"` maybe a `orderby` in the existing query could help

Comment: Indeed (upvoted) -  so, a order by in that source is what we are suggesting here. I was never a fan of sql datasoruces on web pages - the wizard do that, they have helped millions of users, and its easy. But, I tend to dump the data source, and move to code behind - say with my handy MyRst routine posted. That's just me, but I don't use sql datasources on web form pages - I think they are easy, but tend to be too messy for my tastes.